# Express requiere una funcion middleware pero tiene un objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, rest

Estoy modularizando el proyecto que tengo que entregar para la facultad y despues de leer varias formas de armar el proyecto. Se encuentra hecho de esta manera :

*Estructura:*

```
src
--controllers
   --bandas
    ----bandas.js
-- database
-- models
-- routes
   -- bandas.routes.js
-- services
   --bandas.js
-- router.js
-- server.js
```

Para entrar en contexto: Dentro de **controllers/bandas/bandas.js** es donde quiero manejar la request con su response, **routes/bandas.routes.js** es donde defino las rutas de mis controllers (GET, PUT, POST, etc), en **services/bandas.js** esta armada la logica de la peticion a Mongo (Estoy usando moongose).

Entonces, recapitulando, el controller recibe la request y la envia al services, el busca en la DB y le devuelve los datos de la DB al controller y el mismo es el que se va a encargar de mostrarme el response de la request, pero al iniciar el servidor me encuentro con este error:

```
          throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\fedeb\OneDrive\Documentos\UADE - Full Stack\VS Code\Project\WebAppAgendaShows\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fedeb\OneDrive\Documentos\UADE - Full Stack\VS Code\Project\WebAppAgendaShows\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\fedeb\OneDrive\Documentos\UADE - Full Stack\VS Code\Project\WebAppAgendaShows\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at router (C:\Users\fedeb\OneDrive\Documentos\UADE - Full Stack\VS Code\Project\WebAppAgendaShows\src\router.js:10:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fedeb\OneDrive\Documentos\UADE - Full Stack\VS Code\Project\WebAppAgendaShows\src\server.js:27:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Revise varias veces y no encuentro nada mal escrito y creo estar realizando bien la logica, adjunto codigo:

*services/bandas.js*

```
const Bandas = require('../models/Bandas');

const getBandas = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const bandas = await Bandas.find();
        res.json(bandas);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message
        });
    }
};

const getBandasById = async (req,res) => {

    //Declaro una variable que contendra un id
    let banda;
    try {
        banda = await Bandas.findById(req.params.id);
        res.json(banda)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: error.message
        });
    }
    res.banda = banda;
};

module.exports = {getBandas, getBandasById};
```

*controllers/bandas/bandas.js*

```
const bandasService = require('../../services/bandas');

const obtenerBandas = async (req, res) => { 

    try {
        const obtuveBandas = await bandasService.getBandas();
        res.json(obtuveBandas);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            message: error.message
        });
    }
};

const obtenerUnaBanda = async (req,res) => {
};

module.exports = {obtenerBandas, obtenerUnaBanda};
```

*routes/bandas.routes.js*

```
// Modulos
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Controller
const bandasController = require('../controllers/bandas/bandas');

// Routes
router.get('/obtenerBanda', bandasController.obtenerBandas);


module.exports = router;
```

*router.js*

```
//* Importaciones
const bandasRoutes = require('./routes/bandas.routes');

const router = (app) => {
    app.use( '/api', bandasRoutes );
};

module.exports = router;
```

Y desde el server.js lo llamo de la siguiente manera (Solo pego la parte donde llamo al archivo router.js):

```
const router = require('./router');

//* Inicializadores
const app = express();

//* Declaro puerto para el servidor 
const PORT = 3000; 

//* Rutas
router(app);

//* Server Listen
app.listen(PORT, (req,res) => {
    console.log(`Server iniciado en puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

Gracias a todos y espero haber sido claro !

Answer (score 1):

En el fichero router.js, llamas a app.use pasándole un objeto `Router`

```
//* Importaciones
const bandasRoutes = require('./routes/bandas.routes');

const router = (app) => {
    app.use( '/api', bandasRoutes ); // <--- bandasRoutes es un objeto
};

module.exports = router;
```

Porque en bandas.routes.js estás exportando un objeto Router:

```
// Modulos
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Controller
const bandasController = require('../controllers/bandas/bandas');

// Routes
router.get('/obtenerBanda', bandasController.obtenerBandas);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, ya me estaba volviendo chango. Es un objeto porque almacena el body de lo que viene de la DB cierto ? 
Pero ahora, como lo soluciono ? O sea, donde deberia hacer el cambio